# Pass value to a textbox use AJAX / JSON

Tags: php, html, json, ajax

I have te following script and want to pass a value to a textbox using AJAX.

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#searchName").change(function(){
             var name = $("#searchName").val();
    $.ajax({
        'url': 'ontwikkelpunten.php',
        'method': 'post',
        'data': 
        {
             naam: $("#searchName").val()
        },
        'dataType': 'json'
    }).done(function(data){
        console.log(data);
         $('#test').val(data.naam);


            });
        });
    });
```

```
<input type="text" id="test" name="">
```

When I change searchName and check the console in Chrome I see the array, but its still not working.

[image]

Comment: What _exactly_ do you mean by "not working"? Not working _in what way_? What are you expecting to happen? What is happening instead? What debugging have you done?

Comment: Also you are trying to assign using `data.naam` ... but from the looks of your screenshot, `naam` is not at the first level of that `data` object. Looks like `data[0].naam` maybe, but the screenshot cut off.

Comment: As a side, you really should come up with a better `id` name than `1` ...: "*ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").*"

Comment: @PatrickQ I want the value of 'Naam' from my array to be written to textbox with the id test

Comment: @IncredibleHat i have change the id name to test

Comment: If you do `console.log($("test"));` or 1 whatever you have now. What is the output? Are there other ids that are 1? Id need to be 100% unique on a page. What you have should be working.

Comment: @nerdlyist w.fn.init [prevObject: w.fn.init(1)]
length
:
0
prevObject
:
w.fn.init [document]
__proto__
:
Object(0)

Comment: @nerdlyist test.php:40 
[{…}]
0
:
{0: "Marvin", 1: "1", 2: "1", 3: "1", 4: "1", 5: "1", 6: "1", 7: "1", 8: "1", naam: "Marvin", aanvang: "1", aandacht: "1", analyse: "1", antwoord: "1", …}
length
:
1

Comment: `length : 0` whatever you are doing is not finding that input on the dom. We are not getting the whole view here.

Comment: @nerdlyist you had a typo in your `console.log($("test"));` ... forgot the `#` ;)

Comment: @Marvin change `$('#test').val(data.naam);` to `$('#test').val(data[0].naam);` ... I think your object is in a 1 element array wrapper. Maybe.

Comment: @Marvin please run it at `console.log($("#test"));` or 1 which ever forgot the `#`

Comment: @IncredibleHat cool, now its working. One more question, hou I can  pass the data to a checkbox.

Comment: @IncredibleHat I wan't to use my JSON data. 
$("#aanvang").prop("checked", data[0].aanvang);

Comment: You should really make a new question. Diverting and changing subjects is considered going offtopic on stackoverflow. But you just wrap the prop in an `if` statement. `if ( data[0].aanvang ) { $("#aanvang").prop("checked",true); } else { $("#aanvang").prop("checked",false); }`

Comment: Nice  thank you so much, i have change it to  if ( data[0].aanvang == 1) { $("#aanvang").prop("checked",true); } else { $("#aanvang").prop("checked",false); }

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON return is an array of objects (in your case, a single array element containing an object). So when you tried to assign with:

```
$('#test').val(   data.naam   );
//                    ^--- direct object item reference
```

This was not finding the right element to use because `naam` didn't exist in the base array. Instead you need to adjust that to first reference the array element, THEN the object element:

```
$('#test').val(   data[0].naam   );
//                     ^--- first array element
```